# Speeding up a density plot

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning

I wish to plot a function defined by

```
F[rx_, ry_, tau_, a_, sx_, sy_,  uf_] := 
   NIntegrate[E^(-qx^2 - a qy^2 - 2 qx (sx - I/2 rx) - 2 qy (a sy - I/2 ry) - I uf tau Sqrt[qx^2 + qy^2]), 
      {qx, -Infinity, +Infinity}, {qy, -Infinity, + Infinity}];


Psi[rx_, ry_, tau_, a_, sx_, sy_,  uf_] := 
   Sqrt[a]/(2 \[Pi]^3) E^(-2 (sx^2 + a sy^2)) Abs[F[rx, ry, tau, a, sx, sy, uf]]^2;


DensityPlot[Psi[rx, ry, 1, 2, 0, 3, 7], {rx, -10, 10}, {ry, -10, 10}]
```

Values and ranges for all variables are mock, but reasonably close in magnitude to the real values I am interested in.

My problem is, plotting takes a really long time. Is there any way I could possibly speed it up?

I am not overly familiar with the parallelizing of functions. I tried a simple

```
Parallelize[DensityPlot[Psi[rx, ry, 1, 2, 0, 3, 7], {rx, -10, 10}, {ry, -10, 10}]]
```

which did not have any effect, with Mathematica telling me it cannot be parallelized, and proceding with sequential evaluation.

Is there a smarter way to do it?

---

UPDATE

I am now going with the suggestion by @Michael E2. It does work in producing plots quickly, but these are very low quality. In fact, even at `MaxRecursion -> 10` the plot is so boxy one can hardly read it. I should say I am interested in the actual Psi2, rather than Log(Psi2). In the example below my problem should be evident.

[image]

On the plus side, this image took a very reasonable 70 seconds on `MaxRecursion -> 10`. So my question now is, is there a way I can improve the quality?

---

UPDATE

Increasing `PlotPoints` did do the trick. For reference, this is what I am getting for `MaxRecursion -> 8`, `PlotPoints -> 40`in just shy of 4 minutes. The upper bit could use some more precision, I'll decide weighing looks against performance.

Thanks to everyone!

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using compiled function, such as `cf = Compile[{{qx, _Real}, {qy, _Real}, {rx, _Real}, {ry, _Real}, 
{tau, _Real}, {a, _Real}, {sx, _Real}, {sy, _Real}, {uf, _Real}}, 
  E^(-qx^2 - a qy^2 - 2 qx (sx - I/2 rx) - 2 qy (a sy - I/2 ry) - 
     I uf tau Sqrt[qx^2 + qy^2])]` for the integrand?

Comment: `DensityPlot` is the least of your problems. The real pain is the integration. Simply evaluating `Psi[-10, -10, 1, 2, 0, 3, 7]` takes about 17 seconds here. Assuming your plot samples the region with 200x200 points, then you need about 8 **days**! Even with 8 cores in parallel you'll only bring it down to 24h. You need to think hard about this `NIntegrate`. Can you approximate this integral? Can you use a simpler method? Do you have to integrate to infinity for a vastly dropping function such as `Exp`?

Comment: @halirutan that's disheartening. The whole reason why I was trying a `NIntegrate` was to find a result for a function I have no good analytical reason / way to approximate further. I will need to look more into that, then. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you tried increasing `PlotPoints`? Start from low values like 10 and increase slowly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you change to polar coordinates and simplify the coefficients, `Integrate` will calculate the radial integral symbolically.  This reduces the numerical integration to one dimension, over the angle, [which can efficiently be calculated with the trapezoidal method](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/130932132).

```
coeffsubs = Thread[{c, b, a} -> CoefficientList[
     (-qx^2 - a qy^2 - 2 qx (sx - I/2 rx) - 2 qy (a sy - I/2 ry) - 
         I uf tau Sqrt[qx^2 + qy^2]) /.
       {qx -> r Cos[t], qy -> r Sin[t]} // Simplify[#, r > 0] &, (* to polar *)
     r]
   ];
Clear[tIntegrand];
tIntegrand[rx_, ry_, tau_, a_, sx_, sy_, uf_] = 
 Integrate[(E^(c + r  b + r^2 a)) r,
   {r, 0, Infinity},
   Assumptions -> {a < 0}] /. coeffsubs

foo = 0;
ClearAll[F2];
F2[rx_?NumericQ, ry_, tau_, a_, sx_, sy_, uf_] := 
  NIntegrate[tIntegrand[rx, ry, tau, a, sx, sy, uf], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   PrecisionGoal -> 6, Method -> {"Trapezoidal"}, 
   EvaluationMonitor :> ++foo];

Psi2[rx_, ry_, tau_, a_, sx_, sy_, uf_] := 
  Sqrt[a]/(2 π^3) E^(-2 (sx^2 + a sy^2)) Abs[F2[rx, ry, tau, a, sx, sy, uf]]^2;
```

For the density plot, I'd suggest doing a log plot because of the range of `Psi`:

```
foo = 0;  (* counts integrand evaluations *)
murf = 0; (* counts Psi2 evaluations *)
PrintTemporary@Dynamic@{foo, murf, Clock[{0, Infinity}]}; (* progress indicators *)
DensityPlot[Log10@Psi2[rx, ry, 1, 2, 0, 3, 7],
  {rx, -10, 10}, {ry, -10, 10},
  PlotLegends -> Automatic,
  MaxRecursion -> 1,  (* save time; increase for greater quality *)
  EvaluationMonitor :> ++murf] // AbsoluteTiming
{foo, murf}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
(*  {69278, 348}  *)
```

---

*Update on accuracy:*

I compared the OP's `Psi` with `Psi2` at a few points (`rx, ry` = `±10, 0`).  The difference between them seems to grow as `ry` increases toward `10`. The relative difference between them at `rx = 10, ry = 10` is

```
0.00852973
```

Since no error messages were generated, I decide to check whether the difference was simply due to rounding error.  I recalculated the OP's `Psi` at the same point with the options `PrecisionGoal -> 6, WorkingPrecision -> 32` added to `NIntegrate` in `F`.  (It took a couple of hours and almost 3 GB of memory.)  The relative difference dropped to

```
-1.59994*10^-9
```

That is much more in line with the expected truncation error from using `NIntegrate` with either the trapezoidal or the two-dimensional integrations, as well as with the errors for the lower values `ry = -10, 0`.  My conclusion is that the numerical conditioning of `Psi` gets worse when `ry` grows large (around `10` and higher, more or less), and that `Psi2` is relatively stable and accurate.

Comment: This looks promising! Thank you, I'll take a good look at it.